# Setting band names when writing multiple layer rasters using GDAL with Python?

Tags: python, raster, gdal, band

I want to write a raster file (using GDAL+Python) with multiple bands. However, I do not know how to name the bands. Their names are always "Band 1", "Band 2", etc. I searched and found a function that should do the trick but failed (`SetRasterCategoryNames`). I hope that someone could help me how to name when writing multiple-layer rasters in python.

Following code is just an example of writing multiple bands to a raster.

```
        from osgeo import gdal

        #Read projection information from original raster
        path = '/home/12101008/MCD43A1.A2007001.h26v06.006.2016111212159.hdf'
        GRID_NAME = 'MOD_Grid_BRDF'
        DATAFIELD_NAME = 'BRDF_Albedo_Band_Mandatory_Quality_Band1'    
        gname = 'HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"{0}":{1}:{2}'.format(path, GRID_NAME, DATAFIELD_NAME)    
        
        gdset = gdal.Open(gname)
        cols = gdset.RasterXSize
        rows = gdset.RasterYSize
        geoTransform = gdset.GetGeoTransform()
        proj = gdset.GetProjection() 

        #Read example layer to test  
        result1 = gdset.ReadAsArray()     
        #print geoTransform, proj, cols, rows
        
        #Setting driver         
        driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('NetCDF')
        driver.Register()
        
        #Create new file and set parameters from original raster
        path1 = '/home/12101008/Processed/test.nc'
        outDataset = driver.Create(path1, cols, rows, 6, gdal.GDT_Int16, ['COMPRESS=PACKBITS'])            
        outDataset.SetGeoTransform(geoTransform)
        outDataset.SetProjection(proj)       
        
        #Write 6 raster from "result" variable
        for i in range(0,6): 
            outBand = outDataset.GetRasterBand(i+1)
            #Attempted to set band name like this but failed
            outBand.SetRasterCategoryNames(['NDVI'])
            outBand.SetNoDataValue(-10000)
            outBand.WriteArray(result1, 0, 0) 
            
        gdset = None
        outBand = None
        outDataset = None
```

Comment: Did you figure out the issue? I think `SetRasterCategoryNames` does not set the band name actually?

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32609570/how-to-set-the-band-description-option-tag-of-a-geotiff-file-using-gdal-gdalw they suggest: outBand.SetDescription(BandName)
I've tried it without error, but still nothing changes when I visualise my geotiff on QGIS. No updated band names. I would greatly appreciate it if someone knows a way (would prefer gdal and python) to change names in a way that QGIS recognises. There are some suggestions here: https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2013-October/037321.html about editing a metadata file (which I currently don't have and am not quite

Comment: Using the SetDescription() method as recommended by @Dr.E is what I do and it works fine for me when I visualize it in ArcGIS. Maybe there is a bug with QGIS that is worth reporting.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to the following post - [How to edit the metadata for individual bands of a multiband raster, preferably with GDAL?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/290796/how-to-edit-the-metadata-for-individual-bands-of-a-multiband-raster-preferably)

Call the script like this to set your band names:

```
    call python3 gdal_set_band_desc.py input_raster.tif 1 "Desired band 1 name" 2 "Desired band 2 name" 3 "Desired band 3 name"
```

The band names show up correctly in QGIS (tested with version 3.20).

Comment: I've tried this solution, but, as per the name of the function, it only changes the band description, and not the band name. I can also testify to the fact that this is not a QGIS error, as I am uploading the rasters as assets to GEE and there the band name also stays the same as the original. I've also tried with QGIS plugin `Rename Bands`, but that also updates only the description. Does someone know how to change the band name?